# ¿Error en la instalación de angular IO en Windows?

Tags: angular

Tengo node y npm instalados en las últimas versiones pero al instalar angular con : `npm install -g @angular/cli`  me sale el siguiente error:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli
>   C:\Users\David-Eduardo\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\David-Eduardo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> +@angular/cli@1.6.3
>   added 115 packages and updated 1 package in 66.648s

Bueno la verdad no se si sería error o no se instaló o no sé pero aparte de eso.
¿Cómo sabría si se instaló correctamente o si no, pues que me faltaría?
¿Dónde se instalan o están los archivos que angular pone si es que instaló bien?

Comment: debes verificar el la carpeta node_modules y en el archivo package.json

Comment: gracias por responder y esos archivos donde se metieron que direccion ? :/

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿ Que significa estos WARN en la terminal de Node?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161263/que-significa-estos-warn-en-la-terminal-de-node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Se instalo correctamente.**

Ahora, prueba los siguientes comandos.

```
ng --version //Permite ver la versión instalada
```

Ubicación de Angular: `C:\Users\David-Eduardo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\`

---

Para crear tu primer proyecto puedes utilizar:

```
ng new my-app //Crea tu primer proyecto
```

> Te puede llevar un tiempo el `ng new` hasta que instala y crea el proyecto.

Vas a la carpeta donde se creo tu proyecto (`cd my-app`) y ejecutas lo siguiente:

```
ng serve // Servirá tu proyecto en http://localhost:4200
ng serve -o // Servirá tu proyecto en http://localhost:4200 y abre el navegador
```

Comment: gracias por tu comentario ya esta creando el proyecto pero tanto tarda? :/ mira ya va de 30 a 40 esta asi desde hace 30 mins:

Comment: No debería tardar tanto, descarga mas que nada, la creación es rapidísima.  Prueba cerrando la consola por la fuerza, borrando "node_module" de la carpeta my-app y corriendo `npm install`

Comment: Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...                                 eso me salio al escribir ng --version por lo visto se instalo bien no ? muhas gracias por su ayuda. :).

Comment: Si, ya desde el momento que el comando emite respuesta indica que se instalo correctamente, ademas de indicar que se instalo la V:1.6.3. Recuerda marcarla la respuesta, para quienes tengan este problema a futuro. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Saludos 
:)