# ¿ Que significa estos WARN en la terminal de Node?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm, terminal

Hola estoy cargando librerías a mi proyecto con "npm" y continua mente se muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> ***C:\Users\victor\Desktop\michaelgram>npm install --save page npm WARN michaelgram@0.1.0 No repository field. npm WARN optional SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN
>   notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - page@1.8.6 added 2 packages in 31.769s***

Cuando trato de instalar fsevents@1.2.3 no me lo permite.
No se tiene que ver con node, y si esto puede afectar en el futuro a al proyecto.
He buscado por Google sin éxito.
Estoy utilizando Windows 10, y la terminal de Node.js command prompt. 
Pero con el "cmd" del sistema también salían los WARN y con otras librerías también me ocurrió.
Gracias.

Comment: haz creado tu projecto y tienes un package.json ?, trata `npm init -y` primero

Comment: Si @DanielPérez , es lo primero que creo. Pero no termino de interpretar ese error. Estoy con otro proyecto y también me pasa

Comment: puedes mostrar tu package.json, creo que el problema esta ahi

Comment: El problema debe estar en  fsevents, parece que se debe al sistema operativo,cuando intento instalarlo da mas error. Pero me funciona todo perfectamente.                                                          
    `λ npm install fsevents
npm WARN michaelgram-api@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es un error, es un warning (aviso) diciendo que no ha encontrado el paquete opcional fsevents. Puedes ignorarlo pues ese paquete sólo es necesario para MacOS (cuyo kernel se llama Darwin), mientras que tú estás usando Windows.

Para aclararlo un poco más: en Mac OS X, para poder detectar los cambios en el sistema de ficheros (de ahí el nombre, *File System Events*), necesitamos esta librería. En otros sistemas operativos (Linux y Windows) es innecesaria (además de no ser compatible), por lo que no se puede/debe instalar.

Angular y otras herramientas (Karma, por ejemplo) usan estos eventos para recargar en tiempo real los test o las aplicaciones en desarrollo, al detectar cambios en los ficheros con el código fuente, por lo que requieren esta librería para tener toda su funcionalidad en OS X.

Por tanto, a menos que estés usando Mac OS X como entorno de desarrollo, puedes ignorar este aviso.

Si quieres evitar el aviso, puedes añadir la opción `--no-optional`:

```
npm install --no-optional
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, ahora lo entiendo, y se ya se que no es necesario para mi Linux. Muchas gracias @PabloLozano